# Stream Xbox One to Surface RT Running Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-surface, xbox-one

Not sure if I'm on the right forums here or not, but I'll post it here anyways. I was wondering if it was possible to stream my Xbox One games to a Surface RT running Windows 8.1. I don't think it's possible out-of-the-box, but is there a way around this maybe? Maybe could I even make the surface run Windows 10, because I know it would work then. Thanks!

Comment: No; it is not possible, this is only a feature of Windows 10 on x86 hardware

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Surface RT does not run a full version of Windows 8 or 8.1

It runs a modified version called Windows RT 8.0 or Windows RT 8.1. Neither of these are able to upgraded to Windows 10.

On top of that, it also does not have an x86 based processor.

You will not be able to stream your XBOX One to your Microsoft RT.